# My sql query to segregate alphabets from numeric

Tags: mysql

I have a column name send which consists of alphabetical and numerical value not alphanumeric, i want to segregate the alphabetical value and their counts.

suggest me the query? i tried '%[0-9]%' but not able to segregate

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Try the [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try to include some example data or a little bit of code showing what you're trying to do.

But, whatever, hopefully you can apply my example to your problem. First, I'll create a table with a column name "send" as you mentioned:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (send VARCHAR(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
```

We'll insert into that some various values which are numeric and non numeric:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO test (send) VALUES (1), (-2), (3), ('a'), ('b'), ('ZZ'),
    ->   ('test'), (42), ('1.2'), (0), (0123), ('123');
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 12  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Then we can build a query which uses REGEXP to determine if a value is numeric or not:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> COUNT(*) AS `Count`,
    -> IF(1 = send REGEXP '^(-|\\+)?([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$',
    ->   'NUMERIC',
    ->   'NON-NUMERIC') AS IsNumeric
    -> FROM
    -> test
    -> GROUP BY
    -> IsNumeric
    -> ;
+-------+-------------+
| Count | IsNumeric   |
+-------+-------------+
|     4 | NON-NUMERIC |
|     8 | NUMERIC     |
+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Apply this to whatever it is that you're trying. The part which says "send REGEXP '^(-|\+)?([0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$' " returns 1 if the value of send is a number.